# Unrecognized selector sent to instance for collection view cell as a button which takes data from the button to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, macos-catalina

I have a button in main view controller named ViewController.swift and need to take the value of the button to ToDoListViewController.
But it's showing an error :

```
[ToDoCalender.ViewController.DatebtnTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb6b808270.
```

I've tried removing all outlets of the button and set connections again. But it still not working. After that i've tried to use delegate in DateCollectionViewCell and call the DatebtnTapped in the DateCollectionViewCell. Within DatebtnTapped another function dtbtntapped which is defined in my ViewController is called via protocol delegate. But it didn't resolve the problem.

I'm doing this for a project under a course of my university. I'm a beginner.

My original code:

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

   ...
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Calendar", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
        ...
}
   ...
    @IBAction func DatebtnTapped(cell: DateCollectionViewCell) {
        let daydata =  cell.Datebtn.currentTitle!
        let mdata =  currentMonth
        let ydata =  year
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoListViewController") as! ToDoListViewController
        vc.day = daydata
        vc.month = mdata
        vc.year = ydata
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

DateCollectionViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class DateCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Datebtn: UIButton!
}
```

ToDoListViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ToDoListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ListTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
    var day = ""
    var month = ""
    var year:Int = 0

   ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        date.text = " \(day) - \(month) - \(year)"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Here, Datebtn and Datebtntapped indicating the same button. I'm using xcode10 and macOS Catalina. 
How to fix this problem?

Comment: No. I have'nt. But tried to call the action from DateCollectionViewCell using deligate protocol. But it's also showing the same error. @KishanSuthar

Comment: you have use button inside tableview cell ??

Comment: the button is used inside a collectionview cell @KishanSuthar

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@IBAction func DatebtnTapped(cell: DateCollectionViewCell) {
```

with

```
@objc func DatebtnTapped(_ btn : UIButton) {
   let clickedItem = arr[btn.tag]
```

the parameter should be of type `UIButton` use it's tag to access the data source of the table

and

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Calendar", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
cell.Datebtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.Datebtn.addTarget(self,#selector(DatebtnTapped),for:.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use it's tag to access data". i'm at the beginner level. So, many things are unclear to me. I've tried the solution u gave. But it can't access the Datebtn of DateCollectionViewCell in the DatebtnTapped function.

Comment: I've changed the codes of cell in collectionview function and codes of DatebtnTapped in the ViewController.swift according to your suggestion. but it's still showing that "use of unresolve identifier 'cell' " @Sh_Khan

Comment: i've tried and fix some problem. but it's still showing the same error.

```
@objc func DatebtnTapped( sender: UIButton) {
   let daydata = sender.currentTitle!
```

and:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Calendar", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
cell.Datebtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.Datebtn.addTarget(self,#selector(DatebtnTapped(sender: )),for:.touchUpInside)
```